# QGIS: Disabled UI elements still showing up

Tags: qgis, gui

I came across a problem while customizing a (simplified) QGIS UI for usage on a windows tablet.
I managed to turn off all unwanted toolbars, toolbar elements etc. However, when I disable certain elements of the QgsGpsInformationWidgetBase, they still seem to show up in the widget. Might be, that I'm just interpreting the customization options for that widget wrong.
Is it possible, do disable all options except the "connect" and the "add feature" buttons?

[image]

Comment: Did you save and restart QGIS?

Comment: Yes, several times. The customization works for every other element, toolbars, menus etc. It seems to be just the GPS widget.